# I put frame.setVisible(true); after all my component added end up with no GUI window pop out

Tags: java, user-interface

This is the console shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent       to itself
at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at assignment2.Sales.createGUI(Sales.java:71)
at assignment2.Sales.main(Sales.java:95)
```

This is my Sales.java

```
package assignment2;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Sales{

String paymentmethod[] = {"Visa","Master"};

JRadioButton crunchy1 = new JRadioButton("Crunchy Combo 1 - RM 19.70",true);
JRadioButton crunchy2 = new JRadioButton("Crunchy Combo 2 - RM 26.90");
JRadioButton hotvariety = new JRadioButton("Hot Variety Box - RM 28.28");
JRadioButton hotpower1 = new JRadioButton("Hot Power Meal 1 - RM 22.90");
JRadioButton hotpower2 = new JRadioButton("Hot Power Meal 2 - RM 53.90");
ButtonGroup gp = new ButtonGroup();

JLabel item = new JLabel("Select Item");    
JLabel quantity = new JLabel("Quantity: ");
JLabel payment = new JLabel("Payment Method: ");
JLabel creditcard = new JLabel("Credit Card number: ");
/*item.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
quantity.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
payment.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
creditcard.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);*/

JTextField quantitytext = new JTextField(10);
JTextField creditCardtext = new JTextField(10);
JTextArea commenttext = new JTextArea();

JComboBox cmbPayment = new JComboBox(paymentmethod);

JButton done = new JButton("DONE!");

public void createGUI(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Point of Sales");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    gp.add(crunchy1);
    gp.add(crunchy2);
    gp.add(hotvariety);
    gp.add(hotpower1);
    gp.add(hotpower2);

    JPanel all = new JPanel();
    all.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    JPanel panelItem = new JPanel();
    panelItem.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    JPanel panelOption = new JPanel();
    panelOption.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));

    JPanel panelSales = new JPanel();
    panelSales.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

    frame.add(all);
    frame.add(panelItem);
    frame.add(panelOption);
    frame.add(panelSales);

    panelItem.add(item);
    panelOption.add(panelOption);
    panelOption.add(crunchy1);
    panelOption.add(crunchy2);
    panelOption.add(hotvariety);
    panelOption.add(hotpower1);
    panelOption.add(hotpower2);

    panelSales.add(quantity);
    panelSales.add(quantitytext);
    panelSales.add(payment);
    panelSales.add(cmbPayment);
    panelSales.add(creditcard);
    panelSales.add(creditCardtext);
    panelSales.add(done);

    frame.add(commenttext);

    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Sales sale = new Sales();
    sale.createGUI();
}
}
```

One of my error log shows]

```
Internal Error
Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for JComponent [in JComponent.class [in javax.swing [in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]]
```

As I read the guide and some forum they say it is really recommend to put frame.setVisible(true); after all component is added.

I Don't know's why my Eclipse ADT, show this kind of error to me, I have no idea now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is causing you trouble

```
panelOption.add(panelOption);
```

You are trying to add a panel to itself. I think you might have made a silly mistake, or are not entirely sure on how to work with panels. Either way, it would have helped if you already isolated the line where the error gets thrown. Try removing this line and see if it compiles correctly. Or at least, solves this error.

Comment: It solved and my GUI can display already. Another small question is that frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); and frame.setBounds(100,100,500,400); should I put in front of the createGUI() or at the back? @Dylan

Comment: You put that code inside the createGUI() method. After your "setDefaultClose.." for example. (but before the setVisible(true) method!)